# Variable not being recognized out side of object java - OUTDATED

Tags: java, class, object, void

this is my first question so not completely sure how all this works.

So, I've been working on the code for out robot for the FTC (First Tech Challenge). I've recently started on a new class to store most of the code and define everything so I can just call it in the program that we run. But I've encountered a problem. I did discover a solution. But I want to know what is wrong with what I did. Here is what I had before:

```
    private Gamepad gamepad1;
    void variables() {

    int m;
    if(gamepad1.left_stick_x < 0) {
        m = -1;
    }
    else {
        m =1;
    }

    int n;
    if(gamepad1.left_stick_y < 0) {
        n=1;
    }
    else {
        n=-1;
    }

    float x = m * ((float) Math.sqrt(1 - Math.pow((double) gamepad1.left_stick_x, 2)) - 1);
    float y = n * ((float) Math.sqrt(1 - Math.pow((double) gamepad1.left_stick_y, 2)) - 1);
    float r = gamepad1.right_stick_x;
    }

    void driving_Full() {
        variables();
        frontLeftMotor.setPower(-y - x + r);
        frontRightMotor.setPower(y - x + r);
        backRightMotor.setPower(y + x + r);
        backLeftMotor.setPower(-y + x + r);
        }
    void driving_Quarter() {
        variables();
        frontLeftMotor.setPower(0.25 * (-y - x + r));
        frontRightMotor.setPower(0.25 * (y - x + r));
        backRightMotor.setPower(0.25 * (y + x + r));
        backLeftMotor.setPower(0.25 * (-y + x + r));
    }
    void driving_Tenth() {
        variables();
        frontLeftMotor.setPower(0.1 * (-y - x + r));
        frontRightMotor.setPower(0.1 * (y - x + r));
        backRightMotor.setPower(0.1 * (y + x + r));
        backLeftMotor.setPower(0.1 * (-y + x + r));
    }
```

The Problem I'm having is that the r variable is not being recognized outside of the variables() object.

The solution I've figured out for now, is to put the `float r = gamepad1.right_stick_x;` in each of the driving objects.

What is wrong with the first one?

Comment: It's defined in that function, so it's visible only within that function.

Comment: Declare `r`, `x` and `y`  outside of any method, like you did with `gamepad1` .

Comment: It's inside the `variable()` method so it's only visible in that method not outside of it.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I also figured out why x and y we're working, I'm using android studio and it auto imported

import static android.R.attr.x; import static android.R.attr.y;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are referring to as an object, `variables()`, is actually a method. Variables declared inside of a method are only available in that method.

If you want a variable to be accessed anywhere in the class/object, you'll need to declare the variable outside of the method body (at the top of the class).

In the context of your program, you could do something like:

```
public class Foo {
  private Gamepad gamepad1;
  private float r;
```

(Where Foo is the name of your class)

Now that you've declared the variable, you'll want to change

`float r = gamepad1.right_stick_x;`

to:

`r = gamepad1.right_stick_x;`

Any changes made to r will be reflected in the entire object.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have here is realted to the variable scope. I 'm goingo to elaborate a bit about this:

The variables have several scopes depending on how they are defined. Here you have a great [explanation](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html). The short version is that we can consider 3 scopes:

1. *class*: they are the attributes and they are available to all the methods defined in that class.
2. *method*: These are the variables defined inside a function. They are available only on that function.
3. *loop*: This referes to variables created on the loop, which are only accesible on that loop.

Your problem is that the variables in you method `variables()` are only accesible on it. The proper way to get what you want is create class attributes.

Furthermore you should consider adding a constructor to your class to initialize the variables. This is essentialy what you do in `variables()` but in the proper way. Constructor method is always called when you create the object. Let's say that you have a class called `gamepad`. When you do `gamepad gp = new gamepad()` the constructor is being called and initiallising your variables.

Comment: The short version is that...?

Comment: @SteveSmith answer is completed now

Comment: So I could do something like: variables var = new variables() ?

Comment: Yes, you could create a class called `variables`. After that you can instantiate the class to create an object with `new`